# Solo Mining with Diablo-D3 Miner and Stratum

Tags: mining-pools, miner-configuration, stratum, diablominer

I'm using Diablo-D3 Miner to solo mine for a personal project. I setup Diablo-D3 Miner on my machine but since I do not want to download the entire blockchain (currently, over 200 GB) I decided to go with a "solo mining pool" known as [ckpool](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=763510.0). The issue is that they use the new `stratum+tcp` protocol and as far as I can tell Diablo-D3 is using the old `http` protocol. If I try connecting with http I get error: `Cannot connect to solo.ckpool.org: Unexpected end of file from server`

To resolve this issue, I tried using [stratum-proxy](https://github.com/Stratehm/stratum-proxy) to bridge the gap between `http` and `stratum+tcp` however in Eclipse console I'm observing the following message:

```
ERROR: Cannot connect to 127.0.0.1: Unexpected end of file from server
```

I'm aware that Diablo-D3 is no longer being maintained and that there are other solutions available (such as cgminer) which are both faster and more up to date. However, I am using this for a personal project and I'm only proficient in Java so I need to get Diablo-D3 (or something equivalent written in Java) to work.

Thanks